Is genie intellicode 1 progrgrammable with a kinnear chain drive garage door opener?
can a genie intellicode ACSCTG type 1 remote be programmed to work with a kinnear chain drive garage door opener?

Is there an existing wireless control on the Kinnear? As I recall, Kinnear is an industrial door system while Genie is more geared to residential.
